# Difference between <header> and <div id="header">

Tags: html

I wanted to start using HTML 5 semantics for a header on my site, however when I looked into some documentation, I wasn't necessary sure that the `<header>` tag could be used for my site header which would occupy the `<nav>` property. Is that what header could be used for instead of the classical `<div id='header'>`?

Comment: If you want to use HTML5 semantic tags, then `<header>` would be where you put a header.  Did you try?  Did something not work as expected?

Comment: As you can see on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp.  
***The <header> element represents a container for introductory content or a set of navigational links.***

Comment: `<nav>`, `<header>` and `<div>` are all different elements.  Each has their own set of rules.  Read them here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

Comment: or go right to the source [https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element) instead of [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp)

> The  element represents a container for introductory content or a set of navigational links

So it means that some browsers and search engines may look at your `<header>` element and interpret it with some meaning.

---

`<div id="header">`  - there is block element with no additional meaning.

Comment: When we say "additional meaning," does that exclusively mean search engine bots scrapping the site? Or accessibility (screen readers)? Or something else?

Comment: @Majo0od Whatever who supports HTML5 and tries to get as much info about your site structure as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="header">
```

is nothing but a div with id header;
you have to specify it's style in css

```
<header>
```

is a HTML5 tag , which already meant to do some flavour.

It is suggested to use `<header>` in order to get your page fully HTML5 compliant

Answer (score -1):

If you use the `<header>` syntax, the browser knows that it is reading a header. If you want to use the HTML5 syntax I recommend you use the `header` tag.

Comment: I'm not sure if the tags tell the browser anything but if I'm not mistaken it does tell SEO what an element represents.

Comment: you said in other words what I wrote